# Https connection uses wrong certificate

Tags: c#, https, x509certificate

I have C# HTTPS API server running on the local IP address. The idea is to call API methods from different IP address from the same subnetwork and authenticate using certificate. So, I issued self-signed CA certificate and client certificate. When I run application on localhost everything works well. But when I issued new certificate for IP address I use, the app runs using localhost certificate and client shows me that certificate is not trusted. I added test domain to the hosts file and linked it to my IP address - but when I issued CA certificate for this domain browser opens endpoints using localhost certificate.
How to tell .NET application which certificate to use? Why even after I added test.com domain to the hosts file and issued CA cert for that domain, when I run application and open in browser test.com, it opens my app but shows cert for the localhost and tells that connection is not trusted?

Comment: Not a software solution, but clearing the cache of your brother maybe solves it, when there was still an old certificate linked to the site.

Comment: I already cleared cache, didn't help